# PopToRootAsync() is not working for IOS using C#

Tags: c#, ios, mobile

I have a shopping cart page and checkout page.

**1-Normal scenario ( stock available )**

From the shopping cart, the user goes to the checkout page and user hit the next button, and the order is placed, the user gets the order number message. And then I am redirecting to the root page.

**2-Problematic scenario ( no stock available )**

1. from the shopping cart, a user trying to go to the checkout page
2. at this time I am showing the message "stock is not available, but you still want to continue"
3. user hits yes
4. **then rather than loading the checkout page, I am calling the next button function or command by nxt.Execute(null); at the pageload or viewmodel load method / constructor**
5. order is placed and it's showing me the message but rather than redirecting to the root page, it stays on the checkout page.

I am using the bellow line to redirect

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await _navigationService.PopToRootAsync(false).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

The above code works for android and for both the scenarios.

It's C# mobile application.

Comment: Your title mentions iOS, but inside your question you are mentionning android? Do you the problem on one or both platforms?

Comment: it's for only IOS. updated the post.